# C++ boost: loading large (4 GB) files in chunks

Tags: c++, boost, large-files

I am new to Boost library, and looking for correct approach to load/map file in parts like 1 GB at a time.

Please let me know how should I map the first 1 GB then unload and reload the next 1 GB and so on...

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

This http://cnx.com article may help you with mapping the hard disk memory into a memory array:

[Portable Large File Access By Memory Mapped I/O in C++ Using Boost](http://cnx.org/content/m15849/latest/)